# Почему задача перебора всех вариантов принадлежит к классу NP-полных задач?

Tags: алгоритм

Насколько мне известно, NP-класс - это такой класс задач, решение которых нельзя найти за полниномиальное время (отсюда NP - non-polynomial), такие задачи можно решить только на несуществующей реально, абстрактной машине.

Однако же задача перебора всех вариантов - это, как по мне, вполне себе задача, которая прекрасно решается за полниномиальное время.

Так почему же ее относят к классу NP-задач?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NP — это не «non-polynomial»! NP значит non-deterministic polynomial, решается за полиномиальное время, но на [недетерминистской машине Тьюринга](/questions/271063/). То, что они не решаются за полиномиальное время, есть (недоказанная) гипотеза **P != NP**.

---

(Раз уж мой комментарий превратился в ответ...)

Это зависит от того, какие бывают варианты. Например, если у вас параметр задачи — размер множества `M`, а вариантами являются его подмножества. Тогда у вас всего `2^M` вариантов, то есть, экспоненциальное количество.

Или если у вас параметром является количество разрядов числа, а вы перебираете все числа. Количество `N`-разрядных чисел — `2^N`, то есть, снова экспонента.

---

(Экспонента не есть полином т. к. `lim (x -> infinity) x^p/e^x = 0` для любого `p`.)

Comment: хм, интересно